# How to map multiple functions to a ttk button

Tags: python, button, ttk

I have been trying to map multiple functions to a single python ttk button.  It keeps shooting me a conflicting argument error.  What am I missing?

Tried:

```
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="decode", command=reverse, shift).grid(column=5, row=3, columnspan=2, rowspan=1)
```

Tried:

```
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="decode", command=reverse shift).grid(column=5, row=3, columnspan=2, rowspan=1)
```

Tried:

```
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="decode", command=reverse command=shift).grid(column=5, row=3, columnspan=2, rowspan=1)
```

Searched google and I must be searching for the wrong thing.  Help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. Have your button call a single method that calls the other methods you need.

Comment: So `command=reverseAndShift` in the Button definition, and `def reverseAndShift(): reverse(); shift()` somewhere else.